# Jupyter widget not displaying

Tags: widget, jupyter-notebook

Hi I have the following code, when I execute it, I do not see the interactive widget, please help! P.S. The code executes, and the plots are made, and the "interact" function returns the values, but the interactive widget is not shown.
The confusing thing here is that the plots in the function are made, but its only the interactive widget which is not showing.

```
import numpy as np            # Data manipulation
import pandas as pd           # Dataframe manipulatio 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # For graphics
import seaborn as sns
from __future__ import print_function
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets

#calling the widget function here
interact(h, ctr=(0,8,2),resptime=(0,8,2),inpercons=(0,8,2));

#defining the widget function here
```

def h(ctr,resptime,inpercons):

```
total=ctr+resptime+inpercons

if total>20:
    custsatscores=[8,8,8,8,8,8,7,7,7,4]

if (total>10 and total<20):
    custsatscores=[7,7,7,7,7,7,8,8,8,4]

if total<10:
    custsatscores=[4,4,4,4,4,4,7,7,7,8]


newlist=[]



import random


for ii in range(10):



    dummylist=[]
    dummylist1=[]
    dummylist2=[]
    dummylist3=[]
    dummylist4=[]

    rr=[]



    for i in range(10):







        dummylist.append(random.randint(0,3))
        dummylist1.append(random.randint(1,4))
        dummylist2.append(random.randint(0,3))
        dummylist3.append(random.randint(0,3))
        dummylist4.append(random.randint(0,3))




    check=custsatscores[ii]




    if check<5:

        rr=[sorted(dummylist),sorted(dummylist1),sorted(dummylist2),sorted(dummylist3),
            sorted(dummylist4)]






    #Avg Satisfaction, Out of 15, 3 Random,1 opposite 

    elif check>4 and check<8:


        rr=[dummylist,sorted(dummylist1),sorted(dummylist2),sorted(dummylist3),
            sorted(dummylist4)]




    #Good Satisfaction, Out of 15, 2 Random 


    else:
        rr=[sorted(dummylist),dummylist1,sorted(dummylist2),sorted(dummylist3),
            sorted(dummylist4)]





    newlist.append(rr)


    #if(ii==9)

    #bookmark=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    #newlist.append(bookmark)

da=pd.DataFrame()

appended_data = []

for i in range(10):
    data = newlist[i]

    npary=np.array(data)

    npary1=npary.T

    ddd=npary1.tolist()

    appended_data.append(npary1)



    da=da.append(ddd,ignore_index=False)

da.columns = [
  1,
  2,
  3,
 4,
5
]

a=0

countz=0
for ii in range(int(len(da)/10)):


    b=a+10
    e=da.iloc[a:b]

    #custsatscores
    #plt.title('Customer Satisfaction rating'+str(custsatscores[ii]))


    for i, col in enumerate(e.columns):

        plt.title('Customer Satisfaction rating'+str(custsatscores[ii]))


        plt.ylabel('% Patient number'+str(ii+1))

        plt.xlabel('Question number'+str(i+1))


        #plt.figure(i)
        plt.plot(e[col])
        plt.show()
        #print(i)


    a=a+10







return (ctr,resptime,inpercons)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lol i figured it out, just had to remove the semicolon at the end of the 
interact function below!

interact(h, ctr=(0,8,2),resptime=(0,8,2),inpercons=(0,8,2));